# Modify a report in Dynamics 365

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I've created a new (and my first) report in Dynamics 365 using the built-in wizard, and now I want to modify it to join more entities and add columns from them.

Modifying and testing the FetchXML was not an issue using XrmToolbox. I was able to connect, verify my XML and retrieve the expected columns.

Next, I followed some instructions online and installed the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Tools, downloaded the RDL, opened Visual Studio, created an empty Report Server project and added the RDL to my project.

**And this is where my problems begin...**

While attempting to modify the FetchXML in the DSMain dataset in the RDL, I encounter the error "The selected data extension MSCRMFETCH is not installed or cannot be loaded."

I thought the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Tools would have included this extension.

What am I doing wrong?